# Kite for Jupyter-lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, kite

After installing kite for desktop (works with VScode)

```
pip install jupyter-kite
jupyter labextension install "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite"
pip install --upgrade jupyter-kite
jupyter labextension update @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite
```

- Enable Extension Manager
- install and enable `@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite` extension in jupyter
  lab

Kite still not shown in jupyter lab.

> No commands that match 'kite:'

in search

- Jupyter lab 2.2.9
- Windows 10

**Update-not working in Version 2.2.6**

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem after reset my laptop.

First, JupyterLab 2.2.x requires NodeJS to be installed.

Then maybe you can try this way:

```
pip install "jupyter-kite<2.0.0"
jupyter labextension install "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite"
```

In my opinion, `pip install jupyter-kite` will install the latest version of jupyter-kite but the version of jupyter-kite should less than 2.0.0 if user use  **JupyterLab 2.2.x**

The code comes from [The GitHub page of Jupyterlab-kite](https://github.com/kiteco/jupyterlab-kite#installing-the-kite-extension-for-jupyterlab).